# Support of `do..while` Loop In scala

Tags: scala, while-loop, do-while

Hello everyone I am new to scala and after seeing the do..while syntax which is the following:

```scala
do{
    <action>
}while(condition)
```

I have been asked to perform this exercise which consists in predicting the output of a program containing the do..while loop.

```scala
var set = Set(1)
do {
  set = set + (set.max + 1)
} while (set.sum < 32)
println(set.size)
```

After execution I get the following error:

```
end of statement expected but 'do' found
    do {
```

I know that it is possible to convert this loop to `while` (which is even ideal), however I would like to know if the `do..while` loop still works in scala if yes, is it a syntax error (Because I searched on the net but I found the same syntax and no mention of this error)? if no, is there a version from which the loop is no longer supported?

Comment: `do while` is no longer supported in Scala. It was in an earlier version but has been deprecated. This also is very unconventional Scala. I would question the source that asks you to do this "exercise"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use *do-while* in Scala 2.13.10

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/JcGnZS3DRle3jXIUiwkb0A

In Scala 3 you can write *do-while* in *while-do* manner using Scala being expression-oriented (i.e. the last expression is what is returned from a block)

```
while ({
  set = set + (set.max + 1)
  set.sum < 32
}) {}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/JcGnZS3DRle3jXIUiwkb0A/2

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/do-while.html