# Possible forms of function literals in Scala

Tags: scala, lambda, scope

I was looking at some Scala 2 code in a project I am working on that seemed very strange to me.

Suppose there is a method that takes a function as an argument like:-

```
def invoke(
    request: Request,
    block: (Request) => Future[Result]
)
```

The normal form of function literal that I am familiar with, would allow us to call `invoke` like this:

```
obj.invoke(
    request,
    (req: Request) => {
        // a bunch of code
    }
)
```

However, I am looking at some code where the sole argument is *within the braces* like:

```
obj.invoke(
    request,
    {
        req: Request =>
        // a bunch of code
    }
)
```

Are the above two styles synonymous? If not then what is happening in the second way and when should it be used?

I am pretty new to Scala and have been reading from "Programming in Scala" but don't recall anything similar to the code I wrote above.

Comment: Yeah, they are equivalent. The latter form is somewhat more common/idiomatic IMO.

Comment: A block returns the last expression. So in `foo(x)` you can always call `foo({ smth(); smth1(); ...; smthN(); x})`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin does that mean we can use a block at all places wherever a value is expected so long as the last expression evaluates to the correct type?

Comment: @CozyPyjama Well, there are exceptions. For example you can have a type `x.T` for `x: Foo {type T}` but you can't have a type `{...; x}.T` but mostly yes. Scala is expression-oriented.

Comment: @Dima Isn't it even more common to write `obj.invoke(request) { req: Request => … }`?

Comment: @CozyPyjama Just as an example, see emulating do-while in while-do style using Scala being expression-oriented https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74406251/support-of-do-while-loop-in-scala

Comment: @Bergi yeah ... but that depends on how the function is defined. In this case it wouldn't be an option.